# Stopped simulation without error

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I simulated a scenario using omnet-4.6, veins-4.6 and sumo-0.22.0.

I have decreased the maximum power in the network to 5mW to reduce the communication range. At 575s my simulation stopped and there is no error.

The last line in my log file is:

```
** Event #4067132  T=575.018126103175  31% completed   RSUExampleScenario.node[9].nic.phy80211p (PhyLayer80211p, id=359)
```

Can anybody help me please to understand my simulation stopping and how to resolve it?

Comment: Did you specify an end time in your `omnetpp.ini`? Did you try running the simulation in debug mode (`./debug`)? Normally when the simulation fails due to an error in the simulation code, the corresponding signal to jump into a debugger is sent. If that doesn't happen, there is probably a configuration issue, or some piece of code that manually stops the simulation. What's also possible is that your operating system stops the simulation (e.g., due to excessive memory usage).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I defined an end time in my simulation. In fact I defined new routes for vehicles and I decreased the maximum power and that caused the problem. I tried to generate a new .rou.xml file and it works. There is a reason that with such .rou.xml file works and with an other don"t work please? Because I did not well understand this point.

Comment: This is not an error, this is the event. Please post the correct error message

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the Erlangen scenario -- that scenario has an ending. It is a linear platoon of vehicles driving along a predefined path, and at the end the vehicles are removed from the simulation (on the SUMO side). Once all vehicles are gone, that's the end of the simulation. If you open up the sumo files in `sumo-gui`, you'll see what happens and you can compare the time stamps to check whether this is the cause.